# Referencing history within the identifier [PineScript v5]

Tags: pine-script, self-reference, thinkscript

I want to reference to the history of the identifier in the same line. It is probably not possible this way. But it works in thinkorswim. I would want the signal either print +1 or -1 else print the last signal that is either +1 or -1 so it is in a loop & wont skip signals. Is there a work around that? Any help is appreciated!

```
ATRFactor = ta.tr(true)
Avg = ta.ema(close, 50)

Signal = close>(Avg+ATRFactor) ?  1 : close<(Avg-ATRFactor) ? -1 :  signal[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You where on the good way. You just need to declare the variable before using it :

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
ATRFactor = ta.tr(true)
Avg = ta.ema(close, 50)

var Signal = 0.0
Signal := close>(Avg+ATRFactor) ?  1 : close<(Avg-ATRFactor) ? -1 :  Signal[1]
plot(Signal)
```

Comment: Simple var function. Wow. There is no better feeling than when someone fixes your error. THANK YOU! Have a good day.